# Session error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

An unlink method is being called on random pages on both the front-end as well as the admin area of my website. This happens while uploading images from the admin panel as well as viewing webpages in the front-end.

I don't have any session variables in the front-end but I have set session in the admin area. I think this has something to do with image files in my uploads directory. There is a `.htacess` file in `/uploads` to deny directory access.

This is the [php error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFfn4.png) I am getting (link to screenshot).

And here is the code in `\system\libraries\Session\drivers`:

```
while (($file = readdir($directory)) !== FALSE)
    {
        // If the filename doesn't match this pattern, it's either not a session file or is not ours
        if ( ! preg_match($pattern, $file)
            OR ! is_file($this->_config['save_path'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file)
            OR ($mtime = filemtime($this->_config['save_path'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file)) === FALSE
            OR $mtime > $ts)
        {
            continue;
        }

        unlink($this->_config['save_path'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file);
    }

    closedir($directory);

    return TRUE;
```

Comment: Error messages are text. You can just type them in the question: among other things, that makes them searchable and easier to read.

Comment: This is a bug only exist in windows. however it will not happen in production server

Comment: looks like a permissions problem for the file/directory where session files are stored

Comment: permissions for session files are added through the hosting server,right?